# How to get selected file in Apple Quick Action Automator Script

Tags: macos, applescript, automator

I want to adjust an Apple Script Automator code that crops PDFs. The script shows a file selector but I want to rewrite it to a quick action, so it takes the selected file as input.

The original code looks like this:

```
on run
    set sourceFile to POSIX path of (choose file with prompt "Choose a PDF file to crop" of type {"pdf"})
    set sourceFile to current application's |NSURL|'s fileURLWithPath:sourceFile
    set theDocument to (current application's PDFDocument's alloc()'s initWithURL:sourceFile)
```

I changed it to:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set sourceFile to POSIX path of input
    set sourceFile to current application's |NSURL|'s fileURLWithPath:sourceFile
    set theDocument to (current application's PDFDocument's alloc()'s initWithURL:sourceFile)
```

But I am getting this error when executing the quick action:

„POSIX path of {alias "Macintosh HD:Users:armin:Desktop:testfile.pdf", alias "Macintosh HD:Users:armin:Desktop:testfile.pdf"}“ can't be opened.

Any suggestions where I go wrong?

EDIT: Of course, the input is a list (even if only one file is given), so it needs to be in my case:

```
set sourceFile to POSIX path of item 1 of input
```

Comment: Note that `input` is a _list_.

Comment: Oh my, stupid me. Works now.